# MVC 5 Pretty URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, url-rewriting, routes

**Hi there**

I'm working on a system where I have been asked to change the URL in the address line.

To take the short version, we have a profile page for all our lorries, let's say we have a lorry named SuperTransport, so I've made a routing that allows us to access his profile page by typing http: //app.fragtopgaver.dk/SuperTransport, problems are now that when you come to his profile page, something else says in the URL, which says http://app.fragtopgaver.dk/getindex/?slug=supertransport

I need that it still says http://app.fragtopgaver.dk/SuperTransport in the URL when landing on the page.

My routing looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "slug",
url: "{slug}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "show" },
constraints: new { slug = ".+" });
```

And in my Home Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Show(string slug)
{
return RedirectToRoute(ProfileControllerRoute.GetIndex, new { slug = slug});
}
```

and my Profile Controller

```
[Route("GetIndex", Name = ProfileControllerRoute.GetIndex)]
public ActionResult Index(int? page, string slug = null)
```

Hope someone can give me a hint of what i can do about this.

Comment: Your method includes a parameter for `int? page` as well which you did not provide - only the last parameter can be optional.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer was really simple, just had to add

```
[Route("{slug}")]
```

to the controller